# Depositar uno por uno varios usuarios selecionados en base de datos,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

El problema que se me presenta es el siguiente yo tengo una tabla con checkbox, le doy click a varios para que se envien con un archivo que selecione, al darle en el boton de subir archivo a cada usario que selecione en la vista. 
Este es el metodo del controlador. el cual me lleva los datos a la base de datos y los guarda pero no se como podria hacerlos uno por uno y e estado pegado en eso.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
          if($request->hasFile('link')){
            $cliente = $request->input('cliente');
            $proyecto = $request->input('proyecto');
            $calendario = $request->input('Calendario');
            $fecha = $request->input('fecha');
            $anno = $request->input('anno');
            $document = $request->file('link');
            $file_name = time().$document->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('link')->storeAs('boletines', $file_name);

        }

        $file = new File();
        $file->cliente = $cliente;
        $file->proyecto = $proyecto;
        $file->fecha = $fecha;
        $file->anno = $anno;
        $file->calendario = $calendario;
        $file->name = $document->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->link = $file_name;
        $lista = array();
        $add = array($file);
        foreach ($add as $clave) {
           $array =  explode(',',$clave);

           $file->save($array); 


        }
        Session::flash('Exito','Boletin Guardado');
        return Redirect::to('/Admin/file/create');

    }
```

La vista seria esta 

  
    
        
          Clientes

```
      <div class="busqueda" id="busqueda-clientes">
      <div class="buscador">
        <input type="search" title="Escriba Para Buscar" id="buscar-clientes" placeholder="Buscar">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll" style="height:90%;overflow: auto;">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
           <tbody id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"  onclick="toggle(this)" style=" left:" /></th> <!--check que checked todos-->       
              <th>Seleccionar todos</th>
               </tr> 
                @foreach($clients as $client)  
                   <td  id="{{$client->id}}" title="{{$client->nombre}}" ><input id="client{{$client->id}}" type="checkbox" class="valor trigger"  name="checkit"  value="{{$client->id}}" data-id="{{$client->id}}" id="{{$client->id}}">
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    <b class="maxi" data-id="{{$client->id}}" id="{{$client->id}}"  >{{$client->nombre}}</b> 
                      @foreach($proyecto as $pro)
                         @if($client->id == $pro->cliente)
                          <div id="tablaescondida" class="letableu{{$client->id}}" style="display: none">
                            <div class="content-table">
                              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
                                <tbody id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll"> 
                                   <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="g" name="valorproducto" value="{{$pro->id}}" id="pro{{$pro->id}}">   
                                      </td>
                                      <td><b>{{$pro->nombre}}</b></td>
                                   </tr>  
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>                    
                        @endif
                      @endforeach            
                    </td>      
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ella se coloca al dar click en el check  en un

```
      <input type="text"     name="fecha" hidden="hidden"   id="textofecha" >   
      <input type="text" name="anno" hidden="hidden" id="textoann" placeholder="anno"> 
       <textarea type="text"  rows="2"    hidden="hidden" id="textosid"      name="cliente[]" ></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" rows="2"  hidden="hidden" id="textproyecto"  name="proyecto[]"></textarea>
```

Lo que no he podido lograr es lo siguiente al dar click en los checks digamos tengo los usuarios 1 , 2 , 3 , 4   con los proyectos 2 , 1 ,5 ,6 por ejemplo y en y subo un archivo lo que que pasa es que ocupo que sea de la siguiente manera, digamos que en la tabla de la base de datos tiene que ir asi cuando selecione los 4 usuarios 
                         Esta es la tabla y de esa manera tendría que quedar
                         **

- row 1 cliente 1 proyecto 2, archivo 1 
  row 2 cliente 2 proyecto 1, archivo 1
  row 3 cliente 3 proyecto 5, archivo 1 
  row 4 cliente 4 proyecto 6, archivo 1

**

Comment: no entiendo del todo tu pregunta! requieres subir multiples archivos o convertir los checkbox a un archivo separado por coma?

Comment: por ejemplo en la tabla de los checks tengo los usuarios 1,2,3 yo escojo los tres y le subo el archivo quiero subirselos a los tres, y que en la base sea algo como asi id=1  usuario 1 archivo =1   ,,,, como encapsule los tres que en la otra row sea asi id=2 usuario 2  archivo 1 y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
nota: tu input type checkbox debe tener el name como array ejemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente[]">
```

y el php quedaria entonces asi

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
          if($request->hasFile('link')){
            $cliente = $request->input('cliente');
            $proyecto = $request->input('proyecto');
            $calendario = $request->input('Calendario');
            $fecha = $request->input('fecha');
            $anno = $request->input('anno');
            $document = $request->file('link');
            $file_name = time().$document->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('link')->storeAs('boletines', $file_name);

        }

        $file = new File();
      foreach($cliente as $cli){

           $file->name = $document->getClientOriginalName();
           $file->proyecto = $proyecto;
           $file->fecha = $fecha;
           $file->anno = $anno;
           $file->calendario = $calendario;
           $file->link = $document;
           $file->cliente = $cli;
           $file->save(); 
    }
        Session::flash('Exito','Boletin Guardado');
        return Redirect::to('/Admin/file/create');

    }
```

por cada cliente suponiendo que `clinte` sea tu checkbox ingresara un registro
con checkbox 1,2,3 pero con los otros datos iguales

Comment: Digamos el check lo paso con esto <textarea type="text"  rows="2"    hidden="hidden" id="textosid"      name="cliente[]" ></textarea> cuando doy click en los checks los pongo en ese textarea no se si pueda funcionar igual  se me paso eso disculpa

Comment: eso no es checkbox es un textarea :v en se caso cambias  $clients = explode(",", $cliente); y pasas en le foreach esto foreach($clients as $cli){

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('link')){
            $cliente = $request->input('cliente');
            
            $clients = explode(",", $cliente);  
        }
        
        $file = new File();
        foreach ($clients as $cli) {
        $file->cliente = $cli;
        $file->save(); 
        }    de esta manera supongo

Comment: Me da error este error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: seria mas facil si publicas el html para saber exactamente que mandas!

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta y pongo el html

Comment: Ya puse la vista solo que no puedo hacer que se vea bien

Comment: Ya hice que el codigo se vea mejor cuando puedas le pegas una chequeada,Gracias por estarme ayudando, espero y me puedas ayudar @bryro

Comment: tio pero que checks?? hay no hay checks hay un input text y un textarea y ambos ocultos....  esto es un checks: [checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp)

Comment: <td  id="{{$client->id}}" title="{{$client->nombre}}" ><input id="client{{$client->id}}" type="checkbox" class="valor trigger"  name="checkit"  value="{{$client->id}}" data-id="{{$client->id}}" id="{{$client->id}}">  este es el check que tiene el valor del id,  que al dar click se pasa a los textarea y se colocan en el text area de esta forma 7,8,9 con cada check que doy,  el textarea es el que llega al controlador

Comment: Digamos los check que estan en la tabla al dar click en ellos se colocan en los textareas que ves que estan ocultos, y los textarea son los que llevan la informacion al metodo, Disculpa si no me di a entender a la primera me disculpo